# Java equivalent of ruby's "Some sentence that I need a dynamic #{value}."

Tags: java, ruby, string, formatting, string-formatting

Do I have to formulate all of my strings in java like "Some static words" + variable + " some more static words." or is there a way to do something like the way ruby allows you to evaluate a section in a string: "Some static words with a #{dynamic_value} inserted into the statement."

I haven't found much in the way of googling, this would really speed up formatting strings and make them much more viewable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the [`String.format()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) method.

```
String.format("Your static string with %s some variables %d", "string", 3445);
```

The general idea is that you put your static string first with special place holder formatting. (`"%s"`)  Then you pass in the variables to fill into those placeholders.

Comment: Hmm. How does it determine which you're putting where? Is it just the order that you're passing it after the string?

Comment: @dah, yes.  It is just the order you pass after the initial format string.  So, in my example, of you switched the order of the last 2 parameters the code would throw an exception because the types wouldn't match the declared types. (They would be backwards)

Comment: Yes, it is the order but also the type of the data. So if you specify %d and than try to put a string in, it will throw an exception.

Comment: @Casey, yup.  It is also very important to match the correct types.

Comment: @dah, @jjnguy - You can include an argument index in the format specifier, before the conversion. For example, "with %1$s ... %2$d". Localized messages may require this.

Comment: @Andy, thanks for that little bit of info.  I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3):

I don`t know Ruby, but I think that this is what you want:

```
String text = MessageFormat.format("This is {0} a dynamic value", dynamicValue);
```